# Does intellisense work in XCode?

Tags: xcode, intellisense, code-completion

I am a noob to XCode, so forgive what could be a dumb question.  It seems like XCode kind of does intellisense (or code completion).  When I type in:

```
[self setT
```

it suggests the setTitle because its the first matching one.  Is there a way to make it work a bit more like Visual Studio where you get a dropdown of available methods/properties/etc...?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can press "Esc" for a list of suggestions.
You can also turn on automatic suggestions in the preferences.

Comment: doesn't find any suggestions, what is wrong ? Doesn't it work for C++ ?

Answer (score 4):

Fn + Esc will bring up a list of them, and you may have to enable it in preferences

It's not always context sensitive (or gets confused about context easily)

But it still works